# Issue with logical operators in R, using ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, replace

Below is the code I'm using. The idea is that we have a variable "habitaciones" which counts the number of rooms in a hotel. I create a new variable called hrango, which has ranges based on the number of rooms. Hotels with 20 or less are small, between 21 and 40 are medium, and greater than 40 are large. You can see how I tried to process this using operators.

The problem when I run this code, is any hotel with less than 10 rooms is labeled as large, and any hotel with more than 100 rooms is labeled as small, and I cannot seem to figure out why. I started out using code based on "replace" which wasn't working properly, moved to ifelse, and still can't get the result I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
full_data <- full_data %>% 
  mutate (hrango = ifelse(habitaciones < 21, "Hoteles Pequenos",
                          ifelse(habitaciones > 20 & habitaciones < 41, "Hoteles Medios",
                                 ifelse(habitaciones > 40, "Hoteles Grandes", hrango)
                                        )
                                        )
                                       )
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible example

Comment: Would consider using `dplyr::case_when()` rather than complex nested `ifelse()`

Comment: Your problems might have to do with the fact that you used "&" instead of "&&" in the condition. Please, next time upload some data we can work with.

Comment: @Lluís, that is not correct, the `&` is appropriate here, `&&` would be wrong. (I agree about sample data.) (I'm making the `&`-vs-`&&` determination based on the assumption that `habitaciones` is a column within `full_data`.)

Answer (score 4):

1. In general, base R's `ifelse` has some baggage, namely that it will drop class. As an example,

   ```r
   ifelse(c(T,F), rep(Sys.time(),2), rep(Sys.time(),2))
   # [1] 1591376254 1591376254
   ```

   Since you're already using `dplyr`, I suggest you consider `dplyr::if_else`:

   ```r
   if_else(c(T,F), rep(Sys.time(),2), rep(Sys.time(),2))
   # [1] "2020-06-05 09:57:57 PDT" "2020-06-05 09:57:57 PDT"
   ```

   (`data.table::fifelse` is also good.)
2. When I see nested `ifelse`s, I think `case_when` would be better. It isn't often *faster* (it's about the same), but it is much more readable and therefore maintainable.

   ```r
   full_data %>%
     mutate(
       hrango = case_when(
         habitaciones < 21                     ~ "Hoteles Pequenos",
         habitaciones > 20 & habitaciones < 41 ~ "Hoteles Medios",
         habitaciones > 40                     ~ "Hoteles Grandes",
         TRUE ~ hrango)
     )
   ```

   Since `case_when` stops evaluating (for each element) after the first true, you could shorten this a little:

   ```r
   full_data %>%
     mutate(
       hrango = case_when(
         habitaciones < 21 ~ "Hoteles Pequenos",
         habitaciones < 41 ~ "Hoteles Medios",
         habitaciones > 40 ~ "Hoteles Grandes",
         TRUE ~ hrango)
     )
   ```
3. Further, since you're just looking among a continuous range of values, you could use `cut`:

   ```r
   full_data %>%
     mutate(
       hrango = cut(hrango, c(-Inf, 20, 40, Inf),
                    labels = c("Hoteles Pequenos", "Hoteles Medios", "Hoteles Grandes")),
       hrango = as.character(hrango)
     )
   ```

   where the second assignment of `as.character` is because `cut` returns `factor` and I'm inferring you want `character`.

   One more note: I'm inferring that you are using `integer`s because of your overlapping conditions. The `case_when` solution will still work, but if your data is `numeric` then you might need to rethink your boundaries to make sure you are getting what you need. Since `cut` defaults to "right-closed" (`right=TRUE`), it will give you left-open, so `(0,20]` and `(20,40]` means that 20 will match the first, 20.1 and 21 will match the second, etc.

Comment: I think @r2evans that you want the last line of `case_when` to be `TRUE ~ NA_character_` but I do agree it is so much easier to read and revise

Comment: @ChuckP why would you want `TRUE ~ NA_character_`? Check the `ifelse` statement given by OP, if everything fails, give back `hrango`

Comment: @ChuckP, perhaps. I was going off of the original code, so I thought I'd stay consistent with that.

Comment: @ChuckP, another thought: it could be `NaN`, in which case OP may want to preserve the difference between "number", `NA`, and `NaN`. idk

Comment: Ahhhh, see I *assumed* we were creating `hrango` de novo in which case trying to put `hrango` in would be impossible.  Guess that's the problem with guessing at OP's data.  My apologies